# Text field events, rules etc

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield

I am having some questions regarding `JTextField`.

1. Which event has replaced `TextChanged` Event for `JTextField` in NetBeans?
2. When Value in a textField is changed I want its sum to be done and added to `Total` Fee . For same I'm using this code but its not working.

Code:

```
private void TutionFeesKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
   TotalFee.setText(""+Integer.parseInt(TutionFees.getText())+
     Integer.parseInt(LibraryFees.getText())+Integer.parseInt(UDFees.getText())+
     Integer.parseInt(USFees.getText())+Integer.parseInt(OtherFees.getText())+
     Integer.parseInt(SecurityFees.getText())) ;   
     // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Basically I am using:

```
Integer.parseInt()
```

To convert text into numerical data so I can add them ..

I am using `KeyTyped` event , but however its not allowing anything to enter in text field instead.

Comment: 1) SO is not a 'doubt and answer' site but a 'question and answer' site.  So if you have questions, call them that and ask them.  As it is, I see only one question.  2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 3) As to the task:  Consider using a `JSpinner` with a spinner **number** model instead of a text field.  Much simpler for both the user and programmer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use a KeyListener for this sort of thing as it can mess up the basic function of the JTextField. To listen for changes in the JTextField's content as it's being entered, consider instead adding a DocumentListener to the JTextField's Document.

And if you need to restrict the input to numeric or use any other type of restriction, set the Document's filter via a DocumentFilter (remember to cast it to a PlainDocument first), **or** use a JFormattedTextField, **or** use (my favorite) a JSpinner.

e.g.,

```
Document doc = myTextField.getDocument();
doc.addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

        void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

        void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e){
            // ... code to check document change here
        }

});
```

---

For example, use of a DocumentListener **and** a DocumentFilter together, the first to add numbers, the second to be sure that only numbers are entered.

Edited now to handle 15 JTextFields:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DocListenerEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int FIELD_COUNT = 15;
   private static final int COLS = 6;
   private List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();
   private JTextField sumField = new JTextField(COLS);

   public DocListenerEg() {
      sumField.setFocusable(false);

      DocListener docListener = new DocListener();
      DocFilter docFilter = new DocFilter();
      for (int i = 0; i < FIELD_COUNT; i++) {
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLS);
         Document doc = textField.getDocument();
         doc.addDocumentListener(docListener);
         ((PlainDocument) doc).setDocumentFilter(docFilter);
         add(textField);
         fieldList.add(textField);
         String labelText = i < (FIELD_COUNT - 1) ? "+" : "=";
         add(new JLabel(labelText));
      }
      add(sumField);
   }

   private class DocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
      private boolean checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(String text) {
         if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
         } else {
            try {
               Integer.parseInt(text);
               return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
         }
         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         sb.insert(offset, string);

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
         }

      }

      @Override
      public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
            throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         int end = offset + length;
         sb.replace(offset, end, "");

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {            
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         int end = offset + length;
         sb.replace(offset, end, text);

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {            
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
         }
      }
   }

   private class DocListener implements DocumentListener {

      private void textChanged() {
         int sum = 0;
         for (JTextField jTextField : fieldList) {
            String text = jTextField.getText().trim();
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
               sum += Integer.parseInt(text);
            }
         }
         sumField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
      }

      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DocListenerEg mainPanel = new DocListenerEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DocListenerEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

---

Edit: You state in comment,

> Read whole code, much informative , however way too big if i want to implement for more then 30 textfields .. I have solved the problem , now pasting the solution.

OK, so this new code below adds numbers from **100 JTextFields**, again with minimal change to original code. To see which solution works best, to see which solution *scales* best, try to change your current solution to handle something similar:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.PlainDocument;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DocListenerEg extends JPanel {
   private static final int COLS = 6;
   private static final int GAP = 5;
   private static final int SIDE = 10;
   private List<JTextField> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();
   private JTextField sumField = new JTextField(COLS);

   public DocListenerEg() {
      sumField.setFocusable(false);

      JPanel additionFieldPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(SIDE, SIDE, GAP, GAP));
      additionFieldPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Numbers To Add"));

      DocListener docListener = new DocListener();
      DocFilter docFilter = new DocFilter();
      for (int i = 0; i < SIDE * SIDE; i++) {
         JTextField textField = new JTextField(COLS);
         Document doc = textField.getDocument();
         doc.addDocumentListener(docListener);
         ((PlainDocument) doc).setDocumentFilter(docFilter);
         fieldList.add(textField);
         additionFieldPanel.add(textField);
      }

      JPanel sumPanel = new JPanel();
      sumPanel.add(new JLabel("Sum Of All Numbers:"));
      sumPanel.add(sumField);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(additionFieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(sumPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
   }

   private class DocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
      private boolean checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(String text) {
         if (text.isEmpty()) {
            return true;
         } else {
            try {
               Integer.parseInt(text);
               return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            }
         }
         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
            AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         sb.insert(offset, string);

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {
            super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
         }

      }

      @Override
      public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
            throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         int end = offset + length;
         sb.replace(offset, end, "");

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {            
            super.remove(fb, offset, length);
         }
      }

      @Override
      public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
         Document doc = fb.getDocument();
         String preText = doc.getText(0, doc.getLength());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(preText);
         int end = offset + length;
         sb.replace(offset, end, text);

         if (checkIfIntegerOrEmpty(sb.toString())) {            
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
         }
      }
   }

   private class DocListener implements DocumentListener {

      private void textChanged() {
         int sum = 0;
         for (JTextField jTextField : fieldList) {
            String text = jTextField.getText().trim();
            if (!text.isEmpty()) {
               System.out.println(text);
               sum += Integer.parseInt(text);
            }
         }
         sumField.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
      }

      @Override
      public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

      @Override
      public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         textChanged();
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      DocListenerEg mainPanel = new DocListenerEg();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("DocListenerEg");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: And use a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` or `DocumentFilter`

Comment: for restricting letter i am coded an function n it works perfect but for now my main problem is regarding summing the values and in which event should i sum them up.

Comment: @RajitBansal Try pasting text into the field; try calling `setText`, my bet, it's not so perfect. `KeyListener` is NOT how you handle notifications for text component change, this is why there is no longer a `TextChanged` event in NetBeans, use a `DocumentListener` if you want to know when it changes, and `InputVerifier` if you want to do post validation on the field or a `JFormattedTextField` or `JSpinner` if you want to further restrict the user input or a `DocumentFilter` if you want to do real time validation. These are the tools you have to do the job right...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can not find DocumentListner is popup menu in events , do i need to manually write its code or need to install a Jar file?

Comment: @RajitBansal It's not something Netbeans form editor seems to be able to handle or handle well. You will need to create an instance of `DocumentListener` and apply it to the `JTextField`'s `Document`...`TutionFees.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {...});`

Comment: I tried following but seems like netbeans is not allowing or is it wring? myField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

     public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }

     public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }

     public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        // TODO add code!

     }
  });

Comment: do i need to import some package?

Comment: @RajitBansal See [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more details, but yes, you do.

Comment: @RajitBansal: for a functioning example, see code added to answer.

Comment: Read whole code, much informative , however way too big if i want to implement for more then 30 textfields .. I have solved the problem , now pasting the solution.

Comment: @RajitBansal: how does your solution scale better than simply iterating through an array of JTextFields? You can't be serious, can you?

Comment: @RajitBansal: for example, my latest edit now handles 15 JTextFields with no real additional net code. It could do the same for 20 or 50 JTextFields. Can you same the same about your code?

Comment: @RajitBansal: OK, just to belabor the point, my latest edit adds numbers held in 100 JTextFields, and again has only a very small amount of additional code. Again scalability (ability of code to easily handle large problems as well as small) matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (TutionFees.getText().equals(""))
   tf=0;
else
    tf=Integer.parseInt(TutionFees.getText());


if (LibraryFees.getText().equals(""))
   lf=0;
else
    lf=Integer.parseInt(LibraryFees.getText());


if (OtherFees.getText().equals(""))
   of=0;
else
    of=Integer.parseInt(OtherFees.getText());


if (UDFees.getText().equals(""))
   df=0;
else
    df=Integer.parseInt(UDFees.getText());


if (USFees.getText().equals(""))
   sf=0;
else
    sf=Integer.parseInt(USFees.getText());

if(SecurityFees.getText().equals(""))
    sd=0;
else
    sd=Integer.parseInt(SecurityFees.getText());

total=tf+lf+of+df+sf+sd;
TotalFee.setText(""+total);
```